# Como definir o tempo de rolagem da página ao clicar no link de menu e ele redirecionar pra uma seção específica? (com js puro)

Tags: javascript

Pessoal fiz esse código js para quando clicar no menu ir para a seção da página correspondente (utilizando a chamada por id). Como o menu é fixo, no script descontei seu height e sua distancia do topo para não sobrepor ao titulo da seção. Agora estou tentando definir o tempo de duração para ocorrer essa rolagem. Só consegui pelo css, mas sem controle de tempo. Se alguém puder sugerir algo ou ver se o código pode ser mais otimizado:

```
    let menuLink = document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li > a');

menuLink.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', menuTop);
});

function menuTop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let id = this.getAttribute('href');
    let alturaMenu = document.querySelector('nav > ul > li').scrollHeight;
    let topo = document.querySelector('nav').offsetTop;
    let distanciaTopo = document.querySelector(id).offsetTop - alturaMenu - topo;

    document.querySelector('html').scroll(0, distanciaTopo);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definir o tempo talvez usando alguma função com `setInterval` ou `setTimeout`, mas você pode definir um scroll suave com uma velocidade utilizando esta função:

```
function scrollSuave(old, des, atu){
    var easing = function (t) { return (--t)*t*t+1 };
    atu += 2; // move de 2 em 2 pixel. Aumentando o valor, irá aumentar a velocidade
    var ease = easing(atu/100);
    var del = des-old;
    del *= ease;
    del += old;
    document.querySelector('html').scrollTo(0, del);
    if(atu < 100){
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function (){
        scrollSuave(old, des, atu);
      });
    }
}
```

Repare que na linha `atu += 2;` você pode controlar a velocidade do scroll.

Na variável `var easing` você pode definir um tipo de *easing* (estilo da rolagem). No código acima está o `easeOutCubic` (`(--t)*t*t+1`), mas você pode testar e escolher outros tipos disponíveis [neste GitHub](https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294). Basta substituir no código apenas o trecho `(--t)*t*t+1` pelo código do *easing* desejado.

Na linha `document.querySelector('html').scroll(0, distanciaTopo)` você substitui pela chamada da função:

```
scrollSuave(document.querySelector('html').scrollTop, distanciaTopo, 0);
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
let menuLink = document.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li > a');

menuLink.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', menuTop);
});

function menuTop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let id = this.getAttribute('href');
    let alturaMenu = document.querySelector('nav > ul > li').scrollHeight;
    let topo = document.querySelector('nav').offsetTop;
    let distanciaTopo = document.querySelector(id).offsetTop - alturaMenu - topo;

    scrollSuave(document.querySelector('html').scrollTop, distanciaTopo, 0);
}

// Função que faz o scroll suave
function scrollSuave(old, des, atu){
    var easing = function (t) { return (--t)*t*t+1 };
    atu += 2; // move de 2 em 2 pixel. Aumentando o valor, irá aumentar a velocidade
    var ease = easing(atu/100);
    var del = des-old;
    del *= ease;
    del += old;
    document.querySelector('html').scrollTo(0, del);
    if(atu < 100){
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function (){
        scrollSuave(old, des, atu);
      });
    }
}
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

ul{
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   height: 50px;
   display: flex;
}

li{
   height: 100%;
   margin-right: 30px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}

nav{
   background: yellow;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="#s1">Section 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#s2">Section 2</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<section id="s1">
   section 1
</section>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<section id="s2">
   section 2
</section>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```